# What version of Android Wear is on Motorola Moto Sport?

Tags: motorola, android-wear

What version of Android Wear is on Motorola Moto Sport? I look lots of old news about plans to issue, but didn't googled any confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it's **Android Wear 2.0**.

According to news on [Lenovo website](https://mobilesupport.lenovo.com/us/en/Solution/MS122270), the Moto 360 Sport was in-line to [receive this update](https://www.androidauthority.com/android-wear-2-0-smartwatches-737740/) (which was available sometime around September 2017)

One [reddit user](https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidWear/comments/6vr009/ummmmguys_moto_360_sport_updated_to_latest_up/) also confirmed to have received the update (Android Wear 2.0). So chances are that you can now download this update (if you haven't already) also if you want to.